# Syntax to sort more than one column in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sorting, sqlalchemy

I am currently using `SQLAlchemy` to `query` my database as such:

```
returnedOrders = session.query(ORDER).join(RESTAURANT, 
                 and_(ORDER.RESTAURANTSID==RESTAURANT.RESTAURANTSID))\
                 .filter(ORDER.RESTAURANTSID==restaurantID)\
                 .order_by(sortOrders(sort_method))\
                 .all()

def sortOrders(sort_method):
    # Date in ascending order
    if sort_method == 'date':
        return ORDER.ORDERSDATE
    # Date in descending order
    elif sort_method == '-date':
        return desc(ORDER.ORDERSDATE)          
    # Restaurant then Cost in ascending order
    elif sort_method == 'restaurant,cost':
        return RESTAURANT.RESTAURANTSNAME, ORDER.ORDERSCOST(???? Error -
                                           SQL expression object or string expected.)
    # Restaurant in ascending order then Cost in descending order
    elif sort_method == 'restaurant,-cost':
        return ???
```

This seems to be working for the `queries` that only involve one `column`. I'm now trying to figure out how to do this for the last two `if` statements but can't seem to get the `syntax` right.

Is this even possible?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It currently does not work because `order_by` does not work with `tuple` instances. To fix this, you need to *expand* the arguments to the `order_by(...)`. One way to do it would be to always expand (using * [star]) and always return tuples:

```
returnedOrders = (session
                  .query(ORDER)
                  .join(RESTAURANT, and_(ORDER.RESTAURANTSID==RESTAURANT.RESTAURANTSID))
                  .filter(ORDER.RESTAURANTSID==restaurantID)
                  .order_by(*sortOrders(sort_method))  # expand tuples
                  .all()
                  )

def sortOrders(sort_method):
    if sort_method == 'date':
        return (ORDER.ORDERSDATE,)  # @new: return tuple
    elif sort_method == '-date':
        return (ORDER.ORDERSDATE.desc(),)  # @new: return tuple
    elif sort_method == 'restaurant,cost':
        return (
            RESTAURANT.RESTAURANTSNAME,
            ORDER.ORDERSCOST,
        )
    elif sort_method == 'restaurant,-cost':
        return (
            RESTAURANT.RESTAURANTSNAME,
            ORDER.ORDERSCOST.desc(),
        )
    else:
        assert False, "Unexpected sort method {}".format(sort_method)
```